# How to Set ID And Value in spinner

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I created a Data-Base table student which contains two fields like student_id and student_name. This table contains some data for student.

My actual problem is I want to set ID and name of student in spinner like in html select tag, so when select spinner item I must get this ID to get another data from database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have two arraylist for name and id;

```
List<String> sIds = new ArrayList<String>();//add ids in this list
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();//add names in this list
```

Then you can retrive here inside spinner select. It will work even if two names are same in the spinner which may be the case:

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            int id = sIds.get(position);//This will be the student id.
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To add values into Spinner you can do it something like this Test

```
 public class Test extends Activity 
{


 ArrayList<String> InfoStudent = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> IdStudent = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 


   //Here you'll have to make a query to get ID and Name then with 
  InfoStudent.add("TheID" + "InfoStudentReturnedByQuery");
  //TheID should go in IdStudent ArrayAdapter and InfoStudentReturnedByQuery should go in InfoStudent ArrayAdapter

  // Then you create the arrayAdapter
  ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Test.this
            ,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,difficultyLevelList);

                 // Set the Adapter
  spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

If you want to know what spinner is selected you should do something like this :

```
          spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() { 

              public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, 
             View view, int i, long l) { 
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Selected : "
           + TheMainAdapterOfStudents.get(i)+" Student ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               }
```

This only it's a guide how to, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

**1. Declare type Like:**

```
public class Item
{
public long id;
public String name;
}
```

**2. Fill spinner with data (Item[]):**

```
    Item[] data = new Item[3];
    data[0] = new Item(1, "Item 0");
    data[1] = new Item(2, "Item 1");
    data[2] = new Item(3, "Item 2");

ArrayAdapter<Item> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

**3. Get your id where you need it:**

```
Item item = (Item)spinner.getSelectedItem();
return item.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am reading your list correctly, if you want to set an Id to your Spinner programically just use..

```
mSpinner.setId(int)
```

In this code replace mSpinner with the reference to your Spinner and int with the desired Id

Comment: i don't want to set  global id to spinner i want to set id to each element of spinner